# System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException occurred when deletefile function called

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am getting error when I am trying to delete a file from isolated storage. Please find my code as below

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                            {
                                if (store.FileExists("LatestZipData.zip"))
                                {
                                  //Error appearing on below line  
                                  store.DeleteFile("LatestZipData.zip");
                                }
                            }
```

Please anyone suggest what might be the issue.

I think the file is open in code elsewhere, any if the file is Open, how can I close it before deleting it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error,it was due to file being **opened** somewhere in code.The following code helped me.

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream latestZipStreamData = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("LatestZipData.zip",
                                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                    IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
        Stream stream=Zipdecryption.decryptisolatedstoragezip(latestZipStreamData);
        latestZipStreamData.Close();
        return(stream);
```

Hope it helps some one :-)

Thanks